# how to refresh Captcha image in asp.net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, captcha

I used that [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/169371/Captcha-Image-using-C-in-ASP-NET?fid=1615350&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&prof=False&sort=Position&view=Quick) on code project to create my own Captcha image, is there a way to make the image refresh?
I have noticed that on IE 9 the image doesn't refresh during the server validation, but on chrome the image does refresh. very odd

Comment: why don't you use a third party captcha?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of browser caching

Add a random QueryString to image url , dynamically everytime.

in the article link I can see that Image1 has given ImageURL in aspx itself.

You can change the code and make it server side to append dynamic querystring on all refresh

e.g.

```
Image1.ImageUrl = "~/CImage.aspx?random=" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
```

I faced similar problem with images, I try by disabling caching and other tricks , but they not run on all browsers and no gurantee of caching disable all the time , whereas this trick works fine for me as everytime your image sent a new request (different imageurl)

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to browser caching policies, try to make browser do not cache images [w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp)
Not sure it works for ie, but it worth trying.

Comment: thanks
I am interested in a more permanent solution, I want to make the image refresh either way. can I add some code behind to do this?